# List EditForm in MS Sharepoint not getting correct Item

Tags: sharepoint, list, sharepoint-designer

I have made a new custom EditForm.aspx in MS sharepoint on one of my lists, but when I try to edit an item, it gets the first item in the list, and not the one im trying to edit.

I have tried reverting to the old form, but it still keeps doing it.

I am quite new to Sharepoint and don't quite understand how the parameters are being passed, perhaps the error could be there somewhere?

Is the  section where the sources are defined?

It is rather urgent so any tips would be much appreciated. I haven't found any solution online yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the mistake, as the Edit Item button seemed to generate the incorrect ID for some unexplainable reason.

My fix was to create a new empty list, then create a new EditForm and ViewForm from the new forms, delete the webpart, Insert->Sharepoint Controls->Custom List Form. I selected the old (broken) list form type.

I then copied this code over to the old list viewForm and EditForm and it worked as it did normally.

Answer (score 0):

ID item of item to be edited is passed to edit form in the query string like this:
editform.aspx?ID=ItemId. So, first, check if ID is in the url and correct.

Comment: I will do so asap, but what if it isn't? And where do i look next if it is?

Comment: If ID in query string is correct, then the problem is in form controls and you have to find why do they work incorrect. BTW, do you use custom or standard form controls?

Comment: Okay thanks.Standard form controls...I think. I inherited this at the new company I work for, and I'm very new still to Sharepoint. I will only have a chance to look at this again in a few hours, but the more information I have the quicker I can resolve it, as it is quite urgent. Thanks for all the help so far Ivan.

Comment: The ID string stays the default. So it is incorrect in the url. Does this mean the mistake lies in the viewForm.aspx instead of the editFOrm.aspx? Is it not sending the querystring when I click 'Edit Item' in the viewForm.aspx?

Comment: I guess so, check the url of the Edit Item link on the view form. Is this standard button or user custom action?